# bad quality of picture in gnuplot 4.6.1

Tags: gnuplot

I have just shifted from gnuplot 4.4 to 4.6.1. And unluckily found that all the pictures in x11 terminal have lost in quality pretty much (low resolution). It seems to me smth is wrong with configuration of gnuplot (I compiled 4.6 from sources and did not apply any options to configure).

Has anybody encountered with such problem?

Best regards,
  Alexander

upd:
here are the screenshots of 4.2 and 4.6 respectively:
https://picasaweb.google.com/102562667690948164683/212012?authkey=Gv1sRgCPj9s7CH1Z3LgAE#5813182842354188578

https://picasaweb.google.com/102562667690948164683/212012?authkey=Gv1sRgCPj9s7CH1Z3LgAE#5813182919536461282

Comment: Can you post an example before/after image?  Also, could you post what is the output of the command `print GPVAL_COMPILE_OPTIONS` in gnuplot?

Comment: gnuplot> print GPVAL_COMPILE_OPTIONS
-READLINE  +LIBREADLINE  +HISTORY  
-BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY  +BINARY_DATA  
+GD_PNG  +GD_JPEG  +GD_TTF  +GD_GIF  +ANIMATION  
-USE_CWDRC  +X11  +X11_POLYGON  +MULTIBYTE  +X11_EXTERNAL +USE_MOUSE  +HIDDEN3D_QUADTREE  
+DATASTRINGS  +HISTOGRAMS  +OBJECTS  +STRINGVARS  +MACROS  +IMAGE  +USER_LINETYPES +STATS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wxt terminal is indeed what you want.

It is enabled by default in the 'configure' script, so I assume you were missing one or more libraries it depends on, when you ran it. I just tried it with version 4.6.1 from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.6.1/).
The `confgiure` script gives you a list of requirements for the wxt terminal to be enabled. Look for the line

```
wxt terminal: no (requires C++, wxWidgets>2.6, cairo>0.9, pango>1.10)
```

You need C++ (I assume you have that). For the others, on my almost clean Ubuntu 12.10 64bit installation, I needed to install 3 additional packages with their dependencies to enable the wxt terminal option. You want:

```
libcairo2-dev
libpango1.0-dev
libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

On debian-based distributions, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

or install them manually on other systems. If you don't find them in your repositories, you can always get the latest versions from [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/),[cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) and [pango](http://www.pango.org/). When you have the libraries installed, re-run `./configure` and check that the wxt terminal line reads

```
wxt terminal: yes
```

If it does, re-compile your gnuplot by `make` and `make install` and you can use gnuplot as before with nice output on the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are absolutely right, enabling wxt termincal during configuration fully resolved this issue.

Comment: Perhaps I should stress that wxWidget must be 2.8 and not 3.0. I wasted whole lot of time because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try "set term wxt". It works as a replacement for the x11 term and is likely to have better quality.

Comment: gnuplot> set term wxt
Terminal type set to 'unknown'
                  ^
         unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

Comment: No wxt terminal in my gnuplot (