# Gnuplot is not creating a plot window

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gnuplot, wxwidgets

I spent hours on fixing this and now I am posting this here. So I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed gnuplot 4.6.6 from source code (I find the same problem with gnuplot 4.4 also). Initially my issue was [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471291/bad-quality-of-picture-in-gnuplot-4-6-1). I then followed the answer and installed all the packages from source. But after getting nice wxt terminal after I started gnuplot, I am seeing the following message on screen:

```
./src/gtk/dcclient.cpp(2043): assert "m_window" failed in DoGetSize(): GetSize() doesn't work without window [in thread b47ffb40]
Call stack:
[00] wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, wchar_t const*)
[01] wxClientDCImpl::DoGetSize(int*, int*) const
[02] wxBufferedDC::UnMask()                  
[03] ~wxDC                                      /usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/dc.h:789
[04] wxAppConsoleBase::HandleEvent(wxEvtHandler*, void (wxEvtHandler::*)(wxEvent&), wxEvent&) const
[05] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const
[06] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)
[07] wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*)
[08] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)     
[09] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&)
[10] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)    
[11] wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
[12] wxWindowBase::HandleWindowEvent(wxEvent&) const
[13] wxWindow::GTKProcessEvent(wxEvent&) const
[14] 0xb730e122
[15] g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__BOXED          
[16] g_closure_invoke                        
[17] 0xb6d8f0d9
[18] g_signal_emit_valist                    
[19] g_signal_emit                           
[20] gtk_widget_size_allocate                
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
gnuplot: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After some Google search I found [this one](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports-bugs/2014-July/284632.html). This says the following:

```
The fix is trivial.  Change the line "USE_WX=  3.0" back to "USE_WX= 2.8"
(reverting one of the changes made in the most recent commit).  Doing so
restores gnuplot to proper function with wx.
```

So I reinstalled wxWidgets with version 2.8.12. However I have no idea about 'how to change the line' as said above. Where is this line?? How to change it? Will that work? Please help. Thanks

Comment: That post refers to FreeBSD and to the makefile they have. Usually, if you build from scratch it should work to run `./configure` again which should then pick wxwidgets 2.8

Comment: Worked! Start from the scratch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, gnuplot currently doesn't work with wxWidgets 3.0, see the bug report [#1401 changes needed in order to support wxWidgets 3.0](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1401/).

The post you linked refers to FreeBSD and to the Makefile they have. If you build from scratch it should work to run `./configure` again which should then pick wxwidgets 2.8.