# gnuplot cannot set terminal to gif

Tags: gnuplot, animated-gif

I am trying to generate a GIF using gnuplot.

I downloaded and installed gnuplot version 5.0.6 from sourceforge, and am trying to run this example:
[Creating gif animation using gnuplot](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/creating-gif-animation-using-gnuplot.html)

However I can't seem to be able to set terminal to gif, gif is not one of the available options under set terminal.

Has anyone encountered this, and figured out how to enable gif option in gnuplot?

Comment: Needs more information. Which operating system and terminal emulator do you use? Also add error text and specify if you used any package managers to install gnuplot.

Comment: On x64 Win10 gnuplot 5.0.6 has GIF terminal support and it is working

Comment: I am using Scientific Linux 6.9. I downloaded gnuplot v 5.0.0 from sourceforge and installed from source files, acording to instructions in INSTALL file, by doing: ./configure, then make, then make install.

Comment: Do you really need to output gif files? you could simply output a series of png or jpg or anything else then concatenate them to create an animation...

Comment: If you want gif, png, pngcairo or whatever terminal you must build against those libraries, i.e. you must have the respective header files and libraries, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13699021/2604213 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31819448/2604213)

Comment: to follow up: the library is libgd. In scientific linux I installed it by doing "yum install gd-devel" , then I installed gnuplot from source. Now I have gif and png options in gnuplot.